# Problems loading css with Android in Phonegap

Tags: android, css

I have an app in phonegap, when I run the app it works fine in iOS but not in ANDROID. I run the app in the browser and it looks fine but when I run it in Android emulator it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please if possible provide errors.

But for debugging and checking on how to fix PhoneGap or webView in general related problem you can use this code on the start of your Activity (If you have KitKat device, but in worst case you can still use a simulator):

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }`

After adding this to the code you will be able to check the erros in chrome://inspect/#devices and investigate via normal Chrome developer tools

Or check following links on debugging for PhoneGap or/and webView:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging